# How to run python + selenium autotests in GitLab?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gitlab, automated-tests, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to run automation tests written on Python + Selenium in GitLab?
I can't find information on the internet. I know that there is Jenkins, but I want to run autotests in GitLab and then create a report in Allure (if possible)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to run automation tests written on Python + Selenium in GitLab?

It's possible by few ways/types of `gitlab-runner executors`: `docker`, `docker-compose`, `shell`.

Example with `docker` gitlab-runner executor:

*.gitlab-ci.yml*

```
image: python:3.7.9-alpine
stages:
  - test

e2e:chrome:
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome  # it's need to be configured with Remote webdriver in your tests to look at http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub
  before_script:
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt  # you can optimize this step by building your own image with pre-installled requirements and using it instead of current python:3.7.9-alpine image 
  script:
    - pytest /path/to/your/tests
```

It's a workable example how selenium tests on python *can* be executed with `gitlab-ci`.

Full simple example is here by tag 1.0.0 https://github.com/aleksandr-kotlyar/python-gitlabci-selenium/releases/tag/1.0.0

More complex multi-browser examples available by tag 2.0.0 https://github.com/aleksandr-kotlyar/python-gitlabci-selenium/releases/tag/2.0.0

Local docker examples available by tag 2.1.0
https://github.com/aleksandr-kotlyar/python-gitlabci-selenium/releases/tag/2.1.0

Disclaimer: i develop python-gitlab-ci and another python-ci templates for newbies, so i will appreciate feedback and requests in my project https://github.com/aleksandr-kotlyar/python-gitlabci-selenium/